# At least one JPA metamodel must be present! BUT it was generated?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I currently try to create a Spring minimal example for Spring + JPA + Hibernate.

I created the following classes:

AppConfig.class

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AppConfig.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Employee.class)
public class AppConfig {

}
```

AppMain.class

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;


public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        EmployeeRepository service = (EmployeeRepository) context.getBean("AccountRepository");

        /*
         * Create Employee1
         */
        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        employee1.setName("name1");

        /*
         * Create Employee2
         */
        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
        employee2.setName("name2");

        /*
         * Persist both Employees
         */
        service.save(employee1);
        service.save(employee2);

        List<Employee> emps = service.findAll();
        for (Employee emp : emps) {
            System.out.println(emp);
        }

        context.close();
    }
}
```

Empoyee.class

```
package test;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 19 * hash + this.id;
        hash = 19 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (this.id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Repository

```
package test;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    Employee findOneByName(String name);

    List<Employee> findAllByOrderByIdAsc();
}
```

HibernateCOnfig

```
package test;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"test"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

the application.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:h2:./test
jdbc.username = myuser
jdbc.password = mypassword
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.format_sql = false
```

and finally the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.websystique.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring4HibernateExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Spring4HibernateExample</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.191</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

If I try to run the example I get:
...Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

**But I can see the auto generated metamodel file in the target folder. What am I missing?**

Comment: why go on about JPA metamodel when you aren't using solely the JPA API? That SessionFactory/Session stuff is Hibernate API, and has no place in any JPA application

Comment: well mainly because i have no idea, I thought it was needed. Can you strip all useless stuff?

Comment: In a JPA based application, you should be using something like a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to construct your `EntityManager` and a `JpaTransactionManager` that takes an instance of your `EntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: @naros do you have a working example or link?

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth I see the same error message when I try to use hibernate-entitymanager version 5.2.1.Final with spring boot via spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.3.0.RELEASE.

I too see the MetaModel objects generated in target/generated-sources/annotations.

Using the older 4.3.11.Final version works fine - no error. For me it looks like a version incompatibility between the spring boot and hibernate versions, maybe that is helpful.

Comment: I also found the same problem on hibernate 5.2.1 final version so I upgraded into 5.2.2 now it works fine with spring boot 1.4.1